Ubuntu 22.04 unable to boot
I got a message saying my root was low on space.  After rebooting, Ubuntu failed to start.
I've tried the repair steps available here. When I reboot, I get a black GRUB screen with commands.
Boot log is here.
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/sda1: UUID="AF1E-67E9" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="7041897d-e21a-4dcb-9db0-8b187210b41a"
/dev/sda2: UUID="d71e47bd-f2e8-4c24-95f1-9c028ae1e48c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="556ace90-8634-4827-9f74-b215fe456da6"
/dev/sdb1: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2022-08-10-16-21-45-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PARTLABEL="ISO9660" PARTUUID="9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a11-46dc207b42ee"
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: UUID="1212e438-6c8f-4f47-a8dc-650a87775e12" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb4: LABEL="writable" UUID="23921d5e-fb39-4ff0-a687-93adfb355cdf" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="01c6a1a7-d452-f748-a5ca-ae6fbf98f83e"
/dev/sdb2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="8D6C-A9F8" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Appended2" PARTUUID="9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee"
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: UUID="68eb55d7-a7b7-4792-b3f4-5ad4648207ad" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/luks-0623d2ae-3485-472f-8b4f-20c3b0b28bbf: UUID="6Wcrii-1uml-bz1J-BSz7-iLxV-dlHp-u7irgK" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/sda3: UUID="0623d2ae-3485-472f-8b4f-20c3b0b28bbf" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="59c0f21c-3a1f-4a53-b58e-26d1d860c028"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Backup5T" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="459696BF11FF6FE8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Elements" PARTUUID="9d05a4a5-1b79-44b7-89f9-a73b707a8fd9"
/dev/sdb3: PARTLABEL="Gap1" PARTUUID="9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a13-46dc207b42ee"

================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "vgubuntu" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vgubuntu" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/root' [927.41 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vgubuntu/swap_1' [1.91 GiB] inherit
blkid -g

[dmraid -sa -c] no
[dmraid -sa -c] raid
[dmraid -sa -c] disks
[dmraid -sa -c] no
[dmraid -sa -c] raid
[dmraid -sa -c] disks
Please backup your data before this operation.
The settings chosen by the user will purge (in order to enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub-efi of
mapper/vgubuntu-root,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file repair-filesystems


Force Unmount all blkid partitions (for fsck) except / /boot /cdrom /dev /etc /home /opt /pas /proc /rofs /sys /tmp /usr /var

fsck -fyM /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2

fsck -fyM /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda2: 310/109536 files (0.6% non-contiguous), 22958/437504 blocks

fsck -fyM /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 8391668 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Optimize? yes

Inode 8392242 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Optimize? yes

Inode 8401820 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Optimize? yes

Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: 628840/60784640 files (1.5% non-contiguous), 116272167/243116032 blocks

fsck -fyM /dev/sdc1
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
[dmraid -sa -c] no
[dmraid -sa -c] raid
[dmraid -sa -c] disks
[dmraid -sa -c] no
[dmraid -sa -c] raid
[dmraid -sa -c] disks

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will purge (in order to enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub-efi of
mapper/vgubuntu-root,
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed:  unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


Mount /dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root/boot/efi
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root apt-get -y update
Running in chroot, ignoring command 'start'
Purge the GRUB of /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root
grub-efi available

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
hwdata libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 libefiboot1:i386 libefivar1:i386
linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40 linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40 linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-45
linux-modules-6.8.0-40-generic linux-modules-6.8.0-45-generic
linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-40-generic linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-45-generic
linux-tools-6.8.0-40-generic linux-tools-6.8.0-45-generic linux-tools-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
DEBCHECK debOK, grub-efi
DEBCHECK debOK
Please type: sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" dpkg --configure -ansudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" apt-get install -fynsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" apt-get install -y lvm2nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-com*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-com*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y shim-signednsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub-common:*nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub2-common:*n
Then type: sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root" apt-get install -y grub-efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in mapper/vgubuntu-root/etc/default/grub

============= Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ==============

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.2
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root efibootmgr -v (filtered) before grub install
BootCurrent: 001B
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 001B,0017,0018,0000,0019,001A,001C
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7041897d-e21a-4dcb-9db0-8b187210b41a,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0016  MEBx Hot Key  FvFile(ac6fd56a-3d41-4efd-a1b9-870293811a28)
Boot0017* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0018* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0019* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001A* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001B* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001C* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot001D* IDER BOOT CDROM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,1)
Boot001E* IDER BOOT Floppy  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,0)
Boot001F* ATA HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)
Boot0020* ATAPI CD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root uname -r
5.15.0-43-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58610: grub-install
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58610: grub-install
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sda1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58773: grub-install
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58773: grub-install
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root efibootmgr -v (filtered) after grub install
BootCurrent: 001B
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 001B,0017,0018,0000,0019,001A,001C
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7041897d-e21a-4dcb-9db0-8b187210b41a,0x800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0016  MEBx Hot Key  FvFile(ac6fd56a-3d41-4efd-a1b9-870293811a28)
Boot0017* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0018* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0019* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001A* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001B* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001C* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot001D* IDER BOOT CDROM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,1)
Boot001E* IDER BOOT Floppy  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,0)
Boot001F* ATA HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)
Boot0020* ATAPI CD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)
Warning: NVram was not modified.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58876: grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58876: grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58901: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58901: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58907: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58907: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58911: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58911: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58918: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58918: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58959: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 58959: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-122-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-122-generic
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59026: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59026: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59031: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59031: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59036: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59036: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59040: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59040: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59181: /usr/sbin/grub-probe
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[83273]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 59181: /usr/sbin/grub-probe

Unhide GRUB boot menu in mapper/vgubuntu-root/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS entry (sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupdx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdc1 has 
                       1177536511 sectors, but according to the info from 
                       fdisk, it has 9767471103 sectors.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on mapper/vgubuntu-root

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: R06ET71W (1.45 )(1.45) from LENOVO
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 001B
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 001B,0017,0018,0000,0019,001A,001C
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7041897d-e21a-4dcb-9db0-8b187210b41a,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0010  Setup FvFile(721c8b66-426c-4e86-8e99-3457c46ab0b9)
Boot0011  Boot Menu FvFile(126a762d-5758-4fca-8531-201a7f57f850)
Boot0012  Diagnostic Splash Screen  FvFile(a7d8d9a6-6ab0-4aeb-ad9d-163e59a7a380)
Boot0013  Lenovo Diagnostics    FvFile(3f7e615b-0d45-4f80-88dc-26b234958560)
Boot0014  Startup Interrupt Menu    FvFile(f46ee6f4-4785-43a3-923d-7f786c3c8479)
Boot0015  Rescue and Recovery   FvFile(665d3f60-ad3e-4cad-8e26-db46eee9f1b5)
Boot0016  MEBx Hot Key  FvFile(ac6fd56a-3d41-4efd-a1b9-870293811a28)
Boot0017* USB CD    VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55)
Boot0018* USB FDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49)
Boot0019* NVMe0 VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,001c199932d94c4eae9aa0b6e98eb8a400)
Boot001A* ATA HDD0  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f600)
Boot001B* USB HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,33e821aaaf33bc4789bd419f88c50803)
Boot001C* PCI LAN   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,78a84aaf2b2afc4ea79cf5cc8f3d3803)
Boot001D* IDER BOOT CDROM   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,1)
Boot001E* IDER BOOT Floppy  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(11,0)
Boot001F* ATA HDD   VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,91af625956449f41a7b91f4f892ab0f6)
Boot0020* ATAPI CD  VenMsg(bc7838d2-0f82-4d60-8316-c068ee79d25b,aea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354)

a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda1/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda1/BOOT/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
d008780449d7affb8a84d3816b167108   sda1/ubuntu/fwupdx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdc : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
mapper/vgubuntu-root    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    not-far
sdc1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
mapper/vgubuntu-root    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sdc1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
mapper/vgubuntu-root    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sdc1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdc

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 6455A798-C489-4672-8081-375FE6AEADF7
       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
sda2  1050624    4550655    3500032   1.7G Linux filesystem
sda3  4550656 1953523711 1948973056 929.3G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 14.32 GiB, 15376318464 bytes, 30031872 sectors
Disk identifier: 9240A165-D190-4AB6-8A10-46DC207B42EE
       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       64  7465119  7465056  3.6G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  7465120  7473615     8496  4.1M EFI System
sdb3  7473616  7474215      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  7475200 30031808 22556609 10.8G Linux filesystem
Disk mapper/luks-0623d2ae-3485-472f-8b4f-20c3b0b28bbf: 929.33 GiB, 997857427456 bytes, 1948940288 sectors
Disk mapper/vgubuntu-root: 927.41 GiB, 995803267072 bytes, 1944928256 sectors
Disk mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1: 1.91 GiB, 2051014656 bytes, 4005888 sectors
Disk sdc: 4.55 TiB, 5000947302400 bytes, 9767475200 sectors
Disk identifier: 5185E92C-FE05-47E1-AC2A-0D7AEE21F657
     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sdc1   2048 9767473151 9767471104  4.5T Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA Samsung SSD 870:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:2330MB:1792MB:ext4::;
3:2330MB:1000GB:998GB:::;
sdb:15.4GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:SanDisk Cruzer Glide:;
1:32.8kB:3822MB:3822MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:3822MB:3826MB:4350kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:3826MB:3827MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:3827MB:15.4GB:11.5GB:ext4::;
sdc:5001GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:WD Elements 2620:;
1:1049kB:5001GB:5001GB:ntfs:Elements:msftdata;
mapper/vgubuntu-root:996GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:996GB:996GB:ext4::;
mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1:2051MB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:2051MB:2051MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
mapper/luks-0623d2ae-3485-472f-8b4f-20c3b0b28bbf:998GB:dm:512:512:unknown:Linux device-mapper (crypt):;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                                          FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                                                            
├─sda1                                        vfat        AF1E-67E9                              7041897d-e21a-4dcb-9db0-8b187210b41a                          EFI System Partition
├─sda2                                        ext4        d71e47bd-f2e8-4c24-95f1-9c028ae1e48c   556ace90-8634-4827-9f74-b215fe456da6                          
└─sda3                                        crypto_LUKS 0623d2ae-3485-472f-8b4f-20c3b0b28bbf   59c0f21c-3a1f-4a53-b58e-26d1d860c028                          
  └─luks-0623d2ae-3485-472f-8b4f-20c3b0b28bbf LVM2_member 6Wcrii-1uml-bz1J-BSz7-iLxV-dlHp-u7irgK                                                               
    ├─vgubuntu-root                           ext4        1212e438-6c8f-4f47-a8dc-650a87775e12                                                                 
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1                         swap        68eb55d7-a7b7-4792-b3f4-5ad4648207ad                                                                 
sdb                                           iso9660     2022-08-10-16-21-45-00                                                      Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1                                        iso9660     2022-08-10-16-21-45-00                 9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a11-46dc207b42ee Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2                                        vfat        8D6C-A9F8                              9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                                                                           9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a13-46dc207b42ee                          Gap1
└─sdb4                                        ext4        23921d5e-fb39-4ff0-a687-93adfb355cdf   01c6a1a7-d452-f748-a5ca-ae6fbf98f83e writable                 
sdc                                                                                                                                                            
└─sdc1                                        ntfs        459696BF11FF6FE8                       9d05a4a5-1b79-44b7-89f9-a73b707a8fd9 Backup5T                 Elements

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root                                     437.5G  47% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/vgubuntu-root
/dev/sda1                                                     491.8M   4% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2                                                       1.5G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
/dev/sdc1                                                       4.5T   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc1

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root                                     ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1                                                     vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sda2                                                     ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8
/dev/sdc1                                                     fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
luks-0623d2ae-3485-472f-8b4f-20c3b0b28bbf
vgubuntu-root
vgubuntu-swap_1

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 1212e438-6c8f-4f47-a8dc-650a87775e12 root lvmid/x7JH0Y-2B3W-yfiO-5LLt-l2SP-JRa4-6973XR/pJCjpH-LBcn-BvVS-5fWF-tOKg-jEhE-H1Dr7m 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

======================== sda2/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.684581757 = 0.735064064    grub/grub.cfg                                  1

I'm hoping someone can save me from a reinstall.

The boot repair app does not free up disk space. You have to manually delete old and invented files or move them to an external drive.

This question is similar to: Disk is full and now I can't boot into Ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
